# Laravel framework use Routes to hide extensions of page

Tags: php, security, web, laravel

I am new to web app development. Recently, I have been exposed to the Laravel for developing a web site. By convention, it uses /index instead of /index.php. I want to know the advantage and disadvantage of this practice. I assume this can increase the security level. Since the extension can be a hint to some hacker. Anything else?

Comment: I think it's just to 'clean up' the URLs. Kinda de-couples the [URLs](http://www.w3.org/Provider/Style/URI.html) from the implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are [clean URLs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clean_URL). The Wikipedia article is pretty good on explaining it, but the main reasons:

- Search engine optimalization.
- It's more aesthetic.
- Easier to use, read, write for the users and the developers too.
- Easier to memorize and share them.